# understanding jQuery map

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary

I found [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) example that says:

```
var arr=$.map([0,1,2],function(n){
    return [n,n+1];
});
```

Will make `arr` a 6 item array. However, I don't understand why it isn't `[[x,y],[x,y],[x,y]]`

I need to know step by step what just happened. This `map` functions seems very useful, I would hate to don't use it simply because I don't understand its behavior.

Comment: Are you looking for an answer beyond *an array of values, which will be flattened into the full array*, present in that page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$.map` flattens the returned array:

> A returned array will be flattened into the resulting array.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/

Comment: Can't belive I missed that... Well, I guess one lose some focus when listening to Metallica while reading. edit: I will accept the answer like in 40 minutes, I seriously must go

Comment: @mithril333221 One would lose the will to live it it were *St. Anger* ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can double wrap the returned Array to avoid the flattened output.

```
var arr=$.map([0,1,2],function(n){
     //    v--------------v----- flattened
    return [ [ n, n + 1 ] ];
     //      ^----------^------- inserted
});

arr;  // [[0,1],[1,2],[2,3]]
```

---

IMO, you'll be better off using a standard `.map()` function instead of jQuery's non-standard one.

```
var arr=[0,1,2].map(function(n){
    return [ n, n + 1 ];
});
```

For unsupported browsers, you can use the [compatibility patch from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

```
$.map( [0,1,2], function(n){
   return n + 4;
 });
```

result: [4, 5, 6]

```
$.map( [0,1,2], function(n){
   return [ n, n + 1 ];
 });
```

result : [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]

You can check the diference in the return